# How to set date format for JSON converter in Grails

Tags: json, date, grails, converters

I've a method in my Grails controller that should return a JSON, a property of the JSON is a Date object, but when I do:

```
render myObject as JSON
```

the output is like:

```
{
    "dateProperty": "2010-12-31T23:00:00Z",
    "otherProperty" : "aValue..."
}
```

Is there a way to change the default date format used from the converter?

I've tried to set the property `grails.converters.json.date` and also `grails.date.formats` in the **Config.groovy**, but this doesn't work.
Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I generally use a custom Marshaller.  Assume you have the following Domain

```
class Address { 
  String addressOne
  String city
  //bla bla
  Date dateCreated
}
```

Create a class under src/groovy like this

```
class AddressMarshaller {
  void register() {
     JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Address) { Address address ->
      return [ 
         id: address.id,
         addressOne: address.addressOne,
         city: address.city,
         dateCreated: address.dateCreated.format('yyyy-MM-dd')
      ]
  }
}
```

Then in your Bootstrap file do the following:

```
[ new AddressMarshaller() ].each { it.register() }
```

The reason I do it as an array like that is because I have multiple marshallers.

Now, anytime you do `address as JSON`, you'll get the JSON you've described and you're correct date format.  I know this seems like overkill for formatting a date in JSON but this has a lot of other benefits.

Comment: I can create a Marshaller for my object...in this case it isn't an overkill, 'cause with this I can hide the _class_ property that it inject automatically in the JSON created. Thanks

Comment: can you create a marshaller only for one of the properties of Address? and leave the rest to default?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a default JSON marshaller for all Date types you can also use something very simple like shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/694845/1024571). @Gregg's answer is a lot more flexible for individual domain classes.