# Value of date object in a map is changed in a grails controller while using 'as JSON'

Tags: json, grails

In my grails controller, i have set a value to a date object as :

```
def reportingTo = new Date("10/01/2013");
LinkedHashMap dynamicParams = new LinkedHashMap();
dynamicParams.put('reportingTo',reportingTo);
```

Now when i normally print the value of reportingTo as

```
println(dynamicParams);
```

Then the value is *Tue Oct 01 00:00:00 NPT 2013* but when i print as json by doing:

```
println(dynamicParams as JSON);
```

Then the value becomes *"2013-09-30T18:15:00Z"*.
How can i retrieve the same value as in earlier print i.e *Tue Oct 01 00:00:00 NPT 2013*.
I think the date has changed because of the change in timestamp. But cant figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can change the `JSON` date format as you want you just need to set an `ObjectMarshaller` in `BootStrap.groovy`.

> ObjectMarshallers : Simple Pogo/Pojo's that implement the
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.ObjectMarshaller
>   interface

Set it like below

```
import grails.converters.JSON;

class BootStrap {

     def init = { servletContext ->
         JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date) {
            //use any format as you want
            return it?.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
         }
     }
     def destroy = {
     }
}
```

Now if you want different format for different classes then you can create the different `ObjectMarshaller` and register them under the `Bootstrap.groovy`

Gregg has given an quite good explanation for the same you can find it over -> 

[How to set date format for JSON converter in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706293/how-to-set-date-format-for-json-converter-in-grails)

Comment: Your answer can solve the particular issue, but changing the Bootstrap is costly, even now the project has been upgraded to grails 3.1.6, and also implementing this method doesnt show the timestamp, it might have been used in other modules, though it is a great concept. Thanks,

Comment: Well in than case you are left with `format` function of groovy to modify the dates which you are fetching from the JSON.